# hide page from dashboard based on user id

Tags: wordpress

How to display selected page based on user id 
Ex: I have 222 page for user id 2 display page from 11 to 20 
and for user id 3 display page from 21 to 30

How it is possible in wordpress theme `functions.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `pre_get_posts` filter.

The code will look something like this:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'misha_filter_admin' );
function misha_filter_admin( $query ){
    if( !is_admin() ) // for admin dashboard only
        return;

    if( $query->get('post_type') !== 'page' ) // we do not want it to work for posts and any CPT (custom post types)
        return;

    if( get_current_user_id() == 2 ) { // if user ID is 2
        $query->set('post__in', array( 4, 5, 7 ) ); // allow pages with IDs 4, 5 and 7
    }
}
```